# How to configure Firebase security Rules with variable keys

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have data in the following format

[image]

I like to configure the rules such that

1. Allow creation of new items (with unique keys) within the message block
2. Disallow the deletion of existing items ("foo bar" and "hello world")
3. Allow updating of item child ("likes" and "views") for existing messages

I tried the following rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,

    "message": {  
        //allow writing only if the new item does not exist
        ".write": "!data.exists() && newData.exists()"    

        //what write rule do I need for
        //insert data with unique keys 
        //allow update of its child (likes and views)
        //    of existing data
    }
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work if message already contain items.

Answer (score 0):

To allow creation and updating, you want:

```
".write": "newData.exists()"
```

In words this means: allow the write if there is data in this location after the operation.

Comment: how do I set the rule such that it prevents deletion of the key ("foo bar" and "hello world"), but allows updating of the child (views and likes).

Comment: As far as I can see the rule I gave allows that. If not, update your question with the code for 1) a write that you want to allow, 2) a write that you want to disallow.